# CentOS 8 can't boot after cuda toolkit installation

Tags: centos, grub, gpu, cuda

*[Lenovo LEGION laptop with dual boot - win10 and centos 8]*

I was trying to run some YOLOv5 example on my laptop [Tutorial#1](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov5-on-a-custom-dataset/), using pycharm.
to keep it under control I've generated an yolov5 conda environment.
while installing requirements file, I think there was some cuda toolkit missing so I decided to run an installation. checked my gpu cuda version using nvidia-smi command. but I didn't check whether it comply with cuda toolkit version.

After installing the CUDA toolkit on CentOS, the system does not boot. This might be related to new NVIDIA drivers unfit for my GPU (nvidia geforce rtx 2060).

When booting from CentOS, the boot sequence get stuck at:
(can't write all previous lines because I don't reach os cli to save the text)

```
[OK] (many passed tests before...)
Starting Switch Root...
[   6.514970] iTCO_wdt: can't request region for resources [mem 0x00c5fffc-0x00c5ffff]
```

I have modified grub boot by deleting `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau` and replacing with `nouveau.modeset=0` and `nouveau.modeset=1`, but after Ctrl+x(starting boot) , although everything starts well, it ends with fonts that cannot be identified. The displayed grub text is:

```
load_video
set gfx_payload=keep
insmode gzio
linux ($root)/vmlinuz-4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x85_64 root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto resume=/dev/mapper/cl-swap rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap quite rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau
```

Edited:
after editing grub menu -  1. set gfx_payload=**text**
and 2. in linux command instead "quite rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau" now there is "text"

it seems like the boot is ending but I the text is not readable.
here's an example:
[image]

Comment: You seem to have a NVidia driver issue. You can probably boot to your grub menu and change the driver used for graphics to `nouveau` from there, by specifying `nouveau.modeset=1` and getting rid of `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau`.  To get to your grub menu, (a) start yr computer and immediately after the BIOS / UEFI splash screen, hold the Shift (incase of BIOS), or press the Esc (in case of UEFI) key repeatedly, to access the GRUB menu. (b) select the first entry from the GRUB menu, press the `e` key. This allows you to edit the kernel parameters before booting. Please report on results.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. it starts linux and I can see the fonts but then, after cpu cores temperature check text is kind of changing scale.

Comment: any other thoughts?

Comment: I have edited the question to contain more information and typed the grub line

Answer (score 0):

Finally recovered!
I was lucky 'cause my wifi kept working.

In short:

1. Switch to a text console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. [Install](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/) `rpmfusion:`

   ```
   sudo dnf install --nogpgcheck https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
   sudo dnf install --nogpgcheck https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm
   ```
3. Delete existing nvidia drivers:

   ```
   dnf erase `*nvidia`*
   ```
4. Upgrade/generate new distro (That's the magic)

   ```
   dnf distro-sync
   ```

   Comment: [after reboot GUI should finally work.](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/recover-from-nvidia-installation-problems/10544/5)
5. Download Nvidia Driver [MANUAL DRIVER SEARCH](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/)
6. Carefully go through installation [instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-centos-8) - Notice, stage 4 will place you where you were before. Don't Panic...use the instructions

   ```
   systemctl isolate multi-user.target
   bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-*
   reboot
   ```
7. Do your thing :)